# Specified cast is not valid.linq query c#

Tags: linq, casting

I have a table name LibraryInfo with these columns

```
[libraryId] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[libraryName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[mId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[description] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
[updatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
[updatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

I have designed a dbml file to access this table and create a method as follows:

```
public List<LibraryInfo> GetLibraryInfos()
{

    var context = new BookDataClassesDataContext(){ ObjectTrackingEnabled = false };

    return context.LibraryInfos.ToList();
}
```

when I call this method 'return context.LibraryInfos.ToList();' shows me 'specified cast is not valid'.

Is there anyone to help me.

Comment: Try `context.LibraryInfo.ToList();`. Maybe you have another table `LibraryInfos`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ... or change `List<LibraryInfo>` to `List<LibraryInfos>`, right?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: i guess the former since the compiler error is that `context.LibraryInfos.ToList()` doesn't return a `List<LibraryInfo>`. So i assume that the type `LibraryInfo` exists and is the desired type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But isn't it necessary that both `LibraryInfos` and `LibraryInfo` exist? Otherwise he'd get another compiler error for the missing class?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: yes, but only OP knows what he needs. I've presumed that at least the return type of the method is correct.

Comment: context.LibraryInfo.ToList(); gives me error that dbml file does not contain a definition for LibraryInfo

Comment: @A.F.M.GolamKibria Aha! Then you need to change the method definition to `public List<LibraryInfos> GetLibraryInfos()`.

Comment: If I change the method definition to public List<LibraryInfos> GetLibraryInfos() then it generates error 'The type or namespacename could not be found.' There  is another method in  another class as follows.                                                                                                      public List<TopicInfo> GetTopicInfos()
        {
            var context = new BookDataClassesDataContext { ObjectTrackingEnabled = false };
            return context.TopicInfos.ToList();
        }this does not generate errors . so I am confused why library give errors

Answer (score 0):

You probably changed one of the column data types in your table or view after importing the table/view into your linq model.

Just re-import it so the data types of the auto generated model are the same as the db structure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the data type you are using. I recommend to use smallint rather than int. I had a similar some time ago, and later realized that querying tables with "int" data type causes the exact same problem. I changed int to Int16 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

My former answer was obviously not correct. But:

You seem to have a mismatch of types here. `ToList()` on the `context.LibraryInfos` table would return a list of `LibraryInfos` objects (`List<LibraryInfos>`) instead of `List<LibraryInfo>`. So either your method needs to be declared as

```
public List<LibraryInfos> GetLibraryInfos()
```

or the code that returns the items needs to be changed to

```
return context.LibraryInfo.ToList();
```

This really depends on which one you want to return.

---

On your comment to your question:

> context.LibraryInfo.ToList(); gives me error that dbml file does not contain a definition for LibraryInfo

Obviously you only have a `LibraryInfos` table in your data context. This means that you need to change your method return type to `List<LibraryInfos>`:

```
public List<LibraryInfos> GetLibraryInfos()
```

So the method now reads

```
public List<LibraryInfos> GetLibraryInfos()
{
    var context = new BookDataClassesDataContext(){ ObjectTrackingEnabled = false };
    return context.LibraryInfos.ToList();
}
```

Every item you get from the table has the type that matches the table name, as the `LibraryInfos` table is actually a collection of items of type `LibraryItems`.

You may have created a `LibraryInfo` class just because the compiler complained it didn't exist - you need to decide whether you can delete that from your project (look in solution explorer for `LibraryInfo.cs` file). But you can not cast between an item from the `LibraryInfos` table and that `LibraryInfo` class.

Comment: That's not the case at all. aPropertyOfTypeTableT.ToList() should work. I just double checked in LinqPad to be sure.

Comment: The original code should absolutely work. It's an `IQueryable<LibraryInfo>`, so it should be fine...

Comment: I've modified my answer, as obviously the first attempt was nonsense :-)

Comment: I want all records. public List<LibraryInfos> GetLibraryInfos() show error since I have LibraryInfo table. Here it should be mentioned that BookDataClassesDataContext does not contain only LibraryInfo table. it contains 14 table. doesn't know what's the problem in the code.

Comment: @A.F.M.GolamKibria I understand what you want. I've edited my answer according to the comment you wrote to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have solved the problems. Someone has changed the database fields. So this problem occurs.